# Custom report of simple-to-configurable product links showing error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'childsku' in 'where clause',

Tags: magento2

Full error text: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'childsku' in 'where clause', query was:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `owd_catalog_product_super_link` AS `main_table`

LEFT JOIN `owd_catalog_product_entity` AS `child_table` ON main_table.product_id = child_table.entity_id

LEFT JOIN `owd_catalog_product_entity` AS `parent_table` ON main_table.parent_id = parent_table.entity_id

WHERE (`childsku` LIKE '%bl%')

Built report first by creating model for **catalog_product_super_link**

function **_prepareCollection()** contains...

$collection = $this->_superlinkFactory->create()->getCollection();

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('child_table' => $collection->getTable('catalog_product_entity')),
'main_table.product_id = child_table.entity_id',
array('sku as childsku')
);

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('parent_table' => $collection->getTable('catalog_product_entity')),
'main_table.parent_id = parent_table.entity_id',
array('sku as parentsku')
);

function **_prepareColumns()** contains...

**$this->addColumn(
'childsku',
[
'header' => __('Child SKU'),
'index' => 'childsku',
]
);**

When filtering on **Child SKU** column, error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Realized it was going back to find **childsku** which is not in actually in the table, and that it needs to read **sku** from **child_table**.

Added method to set the correct filter index to the column AFTER the addColumn method, as follows...

```
$this->addColumn(
    'childsku',
    [
        'header' => __('Child SKU'),
        'index' => 'childsku',
    ]
);
$this->getColumn("childsku")->setFilterIndex("child_table.sku");
```